# The building is reported to have been badly damaged by the fire

Tags: passive-voice

The title sentence is from an exercise and it is the question itself.

*It is reported that the building has been badly damaged by the fire. The building is reported to **have been** badly damaged by the fire.*

My question is why in the second sentence we use **have been** and not the **has been**. Thank you.

Comment: "to has been" isn't something we say. In the infinitive form it is always "to have been"

Comment: Verb phrases like _is reported to, is said to, is supposed to_ are always followed by the infinitive.

Comment: It wouldn't really make any difference if the initial Present Perfect was changed to Simple Present *(...reported that the building **is** badly damaged)*. And by the same token, *The building is reported **to be** badly damaged*, with a more obviously "infinitive" verb after ***is reported***.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.